# How to wait not thread blocking for a certain event?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing an operator for a RapidMiner-Plugin. This operator is active as long as the main method `doWork()` not returns. My plugin communictates over the network using vert.x. I have a receiver service which is stateful and handels the received messages. This service is running in the same thread (mainthread, the only thread) as the above mentioned doWork() method. But since the operator is nothing else doing than receiving messages and handling them the doWork() method returns after setting up the objects. Instead the method should return after the receiver service receives a finished event. So my question is, how can I wait for this event without blocking the thread, which also handles the messages. At the moment I try to solve the problem using a CombletableFuture but the `get()` method blocks the thread and so the received messages won't be handled.

Comment: Delegate: create another thread that will be blocked on the call.

Comment: I also had this option in mind, but how I write a thread, which only instatinates an object and than dosn't stops? I only know the `Thread` class, where I could overwrite the `run()` method, but the execution of this method would end after the instantination finishes, right?

Comment: Use a single threaded executor instead of creating a thread